# Use SFTP instead of FTP in older version of C# (2010 Express)

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, sftp

I have to change an older C# script (created back in 2010 in C# Express) to use SFTP instead of FTP.  It took some doing to get this script out of an old repository - and to download a version of C# 2010 Express to get the script open!  But I finally managed it.  I have never coded in C# so please be kind.  We have several off-site PCs that need to transfer files to and from the server on their network.  This script is a .dll which is referenced in several other programs on these systems, so I'll need to change the calls to this .dll in those scripts as well.  I have researched using SFTP in C# and from what I've seen thought it was best to install Renci.SshNet, so that has been installed as a reference in the project. What I'm looking to do is change the function below to use SFTP instead of FTP, but I'm not really sure how to even begin -

```
public TimeSpan FTPTo(string strFTPServer, string strLocalFileandPath, string strFTPFileandPath, string strFTPUser, string strFTPPassword)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now;
        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(strFTPServer + "/" + strFTPFileandPath);
        ftp.Proxy = null;
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strFTPUser, strFTPPassword);
        //userid and password for the ftp server to given
        
        ftp.KeepAlive = true;
        ftp.UseBinary = true;
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(strLocalFileandPath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Close();
        Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
        ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ftpstream.Close();
        return DateTime.Now - dtStart;
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        throw ex1;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To upload a file to an SFTP server using SSH.NET, use `SftpClient.UploadFile`.

A trivial example is like:

```
var client = new SftpClient("example.com", "username", "password");
client.Connect();

using (var sourceStream = File.Open(@"C:\local\path\file.ext"))
{
    client.UploadFile(sourceStream, "/remote/path/file.ext");
}
```

---

*There's no relation to your original code. The API is completely different. You basically have to start from the scratch.*