# SFTP with Powershell in a batch script

Tags: .net, powershell, batch-file, ftp, sftp

I've got a batch script which runs via `schtasks` every night on different remote Windows PCs (Windows 7 32-bit SP1).  These PCs need to FTP files to and from a Linux server.  Currently using FTP, the batch script works just fine.

Now the Linux servers are being changed over to use only SFTP.  I'd like to write a short PowerShell script to SFTP the same files to/from the server – I've got Posh-Ssh installed to use in PowerShell on these Windows systems (PS Version 5.1).

Currently the part of the batch script doing the FTP looks like this:

```
REM make temp file for FTP
echo open pos%STORE%               >  C:\temp\temp.txt
echo username                      >> C:\temp\temp.txt
echo password                      >> C:\temp\temp.txt
echo ascii                         >> C:\temp\temp.txt    
echo cd /path/to/use               >> C:\temp\temp.txt
echo put %USERDOMAIN%.ftp          >> C:\temp\temp.txt
echo put posdaily.txt posdaily.ftp >> C:\temp\temp.txt
echo get prod.txt                  >> C:\temp\temp.txt
echo get posdaily.ftp              >> C:\temp\temp.txt
echo quit                          >> C:\temp\temp.txt

REM **** FTP to put/get files from POS Server ****
echo First Try Connect to POS ....
ftp -iv -s:\temp\temp.txt >> C:\log\Daily.log  2>&1
```

Is there a way to use this same `temp.txt` that's being created to pass the username/password/put/get to a PowerShell script that uses Posh-Ssh?  What changes would I need to make to the `temp.txt` file?

I can call a separate batch script which runs the PowerShell script – I've done that in previous batch scripts – but I'm not sure how to write the PowerShell script – what command/commands would I use in the PowerShell script to use the data in `temp.txt`?

If I get it working in PowerShell, I should be able to put a call to this same PowerShell script in a C# and VB script that need to do that same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use this same temp.txt that's being created to pass the username/password/put/get to a Powershell script that uses Posh-Ssh?

No you cannot. Posh-Ssh is a native PowerShell module, which does not consume scripts like `ftp` does.

Also as @SomethingDark already commented, there's no need to switch to PowerShell for SFTP. Not even for C#/VB.NET. *What is the difference between calling a PowerShell script and a batch file from C#/VB.NET?*

For SFTP in a batch file, see:
[Secure FTP using Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16150152/850848)

My answer there suggest using *(my)* [WinSCP SFTP client](https://winscp.net/).
And WinSCP can actually consume a script similar (while not identical) to `ftp`. And there is a [guide for converting `ftp` script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

---

Though if you aim to have a same/similar code for PowerShell/C#/VB.NET, you better use an SFTP .NET assembly. See [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848).

If you want a native .NET assembly, I would recommend [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) (though its development ceased in last few years). *And you actually [use that already, don't you?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58524441/850848)*

WinSCP also [has .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) – but it's not a completely native .NET assembly. On the other hand, WinSCP GUI can [generate a code template for SFTP for all of PowerShell, C#, and VB.NET](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code).

*Though why don't you implement your transfer functionality into a custom assembly and reuse it from all of PowerShell/C#/VB.NET?*